# Placing cameras like a triangle

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, coordinates

I am trying to place the cameras in a equilateral triangle fashion. But, I am quite not sure if my coordinates are correct. How do I find co-ordinates to arrange them in a equilateral triangle? Thanks a lot.
Below is the code snippet.

```
 cam_object1.location = (245,-340,226)
 cam_object2.location = (295,-283,232)
 cam_object3.location = (345,-340,236)
```

Comment: My first though is to Add a Mesh Circle and set the Vertices to 3. This will create an equilateral triangle. Place/rotate it as needed and the in Edit mode check the vertex locations in the Transform Properties <kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58187/how-can-i-arrange-items-in-a-circle-using-python)  To test for equilateral triangle, all coordinates will be equally distant from other two, and the angle between them 60 degrees.

Comment: @rob, Thanks for your reply. But since I am a beginner, it is kind of difficult to follow you. Would you mind explaining it again?

Comment: @batFINGER, Yeah, that is what I want to know. How do we measure that?

Comment: If `p1` is cam location (vector), then the distance from `p1` to `p2` is  `(p2 - p1).length`  This [recent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116208/15543) shows an example of calculating the angle between.  Can you re-jig your question re how you wish to determine these coordinates, as there are an infinite set of possibilities.